# Preserving areas in the Euclidean plane

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, functions, euclidean-geometry, area

> Let $f(t;x)$ and $g(x)=x$ for $x,f \in (0,1)$ and parameter $t \in \Bbb R_{\gt 0}.$ Is there a function that divides $R=(0,1)^2$ into pairs of equal area for all $t?$

Define $f(t;x)=(1-x)^t$ and $g(x)=x.$ Clearly for $t=1$ we are successful. But this is the only $t$ for which the constraints are met, so this choice fails.

Basically want $A+B=C$ for some constant $C$ that holds for all $t\in \Bbb R_{\gt 0}.$

[image]

Comment: I do not understand this question. You need to have a clearer description.

Comment: Sure - I will update it to be clearer.

Comment: $f(t;x)=(1-x^t)^{1/t}$ works I believe.